# Задача по программированию в *nix'ах

Tags: unix, c++, linux

Коллеги! Еще одна забавная задача по программированию в Unix.

Вот такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << "HELLO  ";
    fork();
}
```

Что эта программа будет выводить и почему?

Comment: хмм.. а что такое fork? :)

Comment: @Crasher, если незнакомы с программированием в юникс, то гугль в помощь)))

Comment: На самом деле, это задача не столько на запуск новых процессов (хотя и на это тоже), сколько на понимание механизма ввода-вывода в С++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В c++ cout << , в C printf () выводят в stdout. Реально данные пишутся в буфер. Буфер выталкивается (системный вызов write()) на устройство для stdout и tty (консоль) по '\n', если конечно ранее принудительно не задавали другой тип буферизации (например unbuffered). IMHO функции setbuf(), setlinebuf() и т.п. см. man -k ...

А вот '\n'-то и нет !

В твоем примере сразу за записью в буфер идет fork(). Порождается новый процесс, **все данные дублируются** (ну, я не буду о pid, ppid и подобном), а вызов fork() возвращает свой результат в одну и ту же точку в обоих процессах. Далее процессы исполняют независимо друг от друга одну и ту же программу.

Естественно оба в конце концов (по окончании main) делают write(1,"HELLO  ",7); т.е. выталкивают буфер на устройство. Точно не знаю, но думаю, что был вызов atexit(), в котором запланирован вызов функции fflush(), выталкивающей буфера по окончании main().

Насколько помню, чтобы избежать этого (похоронить данные в буферах) надо явно вызвать _exit().

IMHO понятно (в некоторых деталях мог ошибиться, пишу по памяти, да и *nix-ы м.б. разными).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню из QNX, fork() создает дочерний процесс. И еще, на сколько я помню, этой функции в качестве параметра передается адрес функции для нового процесса. В данном случае логично предположить, что он создает дочерний процесс с адресом вызывающей функции, этим дело и заканчивается, так как главный процесс закончился.

Comment: Тут следует учесть время запуска дочернего процесса. Если это время меньше выхода из главной программы, то в выводе мы увидим больше одного `HELLO`.

Comment: Ну, собсно, это я не стал писать :) По-моему, мало-мальски соображающий человек это додумает...

Comment: @RomanoO, не знаю, как в QNX, но согласно POSIX системный вызов fork() не получает никакого аргумента.

Comment: Ну я же написал, "на сколько помню". Давно это было. Нынче я на java и Android. Во всяком случае, даже если не в fork(), то в какую-то из связанных с этой темой функцию или структуру передается адрес функции для нового процесса.

Comment: Это Вы наверно с pthread_create спутали.

Comment: На самом деле, это задача не столько на запуск новых процессов (хотя и на них тоже), сколько на понимание механизма ввода-вывода в С++.

Comment: Скорее с `clone(2)`

Comment: Очень может быть...

Answer (score 0):

```
HELLO
processreturned 0 (0x0) execution time : 0.008 s
Press ENTER to continue.
HELLO
```

Comment: Дивненько. Программку Вы скомпилировали и даже запустили. А почему так?

Comment: Игорь,А вы хотели просто HELLO HELLO? Можно и так :)

Comment: Главное  - объяснить, почему выводится 2 раза.

Comment: Вот, хотел написать, что 2 раза HELLO, но на Познера отвлекся и уже ответили. 

Реально вывод будет по write() из fflush() из exit() (неявного, по оконанию программы) **в обоих процессах**. Поэтому 2 раза.

Comment: @avp, чую, истина уже близко. Тут главное, конечно, объяснить почему. Напиши ответ и немного пояснее.